# IDEA Spring MessageSource note "unknown encoding",what i should config in xml?

Tags: spring

I use IDEA learn  Spring MessageSource,but the beans config xml notes follows error:

[image: 7dqiYF.png]

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
 <bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>format</value>
            <value>exceptions</value>
            <value>windows</value>
        </list>
    </property>
   </bean>
 </beans>
```

and my xml config file list is here:

[image: 7dbxLq.png]

my code is run well,but this error just make me uncomfortable.

thx,everyone.

Comment: it could be due to "windows" is a viable "variant" (i.e. "platform", "architecture", "os-version",..) for message/resource bundles... so "windoofs" (some "less reserved word"), could already make it better. Imagine/try also: setting message source basename "en" or "en_US" ..might also cause confusion in IDE/application.. (more specific "variant" has precedence over less specific/general variants..)

Comment: ..generally i would *not recommend*: using any (iso) locale as base name, nor "platform" (windows, linux, mac...)